# Catch the mouse event

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtextedit, qmainwindow, qmouseevent

Don't know exactly how to give the parameters of QMouseEvent class. Should I create new class to implement a QMouseEvent into my QTextEdit?

```
class Test(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.txt = QTextEdit(self)
        self.txt.setMouseTracking(True)
        
        self.txt.mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent())

class Test2(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        print("text edit is clicked")

ui = Test()
ui.show()
```

Comment: Your question is confusing, please explain yourself better.

Comment: Sorry I edited it. Can you please try to understand it again for me. Thank you.

Comment: I understand your objective better but it would be good if you take advantage of the post (not just the title) to clearly explain your objective. I don't understand what the Qt documentation has to do with your problem, IMHO it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Since many times it is asked how to detect the events that affect a widget then in this answer I will detail the solution and it will be used as a canonical answer for future questions.</sub>

To detect an event from a widget there are several solutions:

#### - Override a method

If the widget has a method that handles that event then an option is to override that method and associate it with a signal so that other objects can be notified.

In the particular case of the mouse release event, this is handled by the mouseReleaseEvent method.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class TextEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    released = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self.released.emit()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.textedit = TextEdit()
        self.textedit.released.connect(self.handle_released)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textedit)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def handle_released(self):
        print("released")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

#### - Use an event filter

Qt allows you to monitor the events using an event filter, so you can take advantage of this feature to emit a signal in a similar way to the previous solution.

In the case of classes that inherit from QAbstractScrollArea, the mouse methods are transmitted to the viewport, so that object must be monitored.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class ReleaseFilter(QtCore.QObject):
    released = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__(widget)
        self._widget = widget
        self.widget.installEventFilter(self)

    @property
    def widget(self):
        return self._widget

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.widget and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
            self.released.emit()
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.textedit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        rf = ReleaseFilter(self.textedit.viewport())
        rf.released.connect(self.handle_released)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textedit)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def handle_released(self):
        print("released")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```